# Calculate forces on a box

Tags: c#, opengl, physics, cad

Story: I am developing a construction tool for wooden boxes. A box consists of a set of boards, each board is represented as 3 3D-vectors, and one placement vector. Each box is visualized using OpenGL.

Now, these boxes will be moved around with forklifts, which will apply some forces on them. I would like to calculate the forces on each board in the box, such that I can see if a given construction is stronger than another, if any board is stressed too much etc.

How should I attack this problem? Are there libraries available I can use? Which books should I read to guide me on this? Can I use existing CAD tools to do the physics experiments?

I am using C# to compute everything, but this is not a requirement (though it would be nice).

Edit: What about libraries such as ODE and Bullet? Won't they be able to answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can implement any computational devices here, you need some modelling. The problem of forces and stresses over a problem like this, with changing set-ups is a very complex one. What you do in Civil Engineering normally is modelling the building (or in this case the box) and use a finite element program to calculate stresses and forces. You need to make assumptions regarding the resistance of the materials.

In short, get a Civil Engineer or someone very knowledgeable in material physics to help you.

Comment: I have considered that. Regarding the assumptions of the resistance of the material: I plan to just calculate the newtonian force on each board, such that each board has infinite strength. I do not know if this is feasible though.

Comment: @Benjamin: the "infinite strength" approach you suggest isn't going to get you there because, say, when lifted by a forklift, if the bottom were infinitely stiff, the sides wouldn't need to contribute to the strength of the box. But, the sides are the major contributor in this scenario.  You can see by this why a model that simultaneously takes all the parts and their stiffnesses into account is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I second tekBlues' answer; you need a real civil engineer to work with on this.  In particular, ODE and Bullet cannot help you.  Both are designed around the physics simulation needs of video games: simulating the movement of unbreakable rigid bodies composed of primitive shapes *very quickly*.  *How* they do this is only vaguely related to the workings of Newtonian mechanics.  In particular, they don't keep track of forces propagating through a system of objects in any way that's useful to you.

I'm sure software packages exist to do this sort of thing, but I'm not personally familiar with any.  Again, you need someone with experience doing engineering simulations.

Comment: I guess you're right on both ODE and Bullet. Reading the manuals doesn't really sketch up how to do stuff like this.

Thanks for your recommendation on the Civil Engineer though, it seems reasonable that this is the way to go.